# Question about the differential of the Gauss map

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

I am working on elementary differential geometry and don't understand the following point:
Let $S$ be a surface and let $\phi(u,v)$ be a local parametrisation of $S$ at $p \in S$. Why we have than that
$$dN_p(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u})=\frac{\partial (N \circ \phi)}{\partial u}$$
where $N$ denotes the Gauss map.

Many thanks for some help!

Comment: It is a direct application of the definition of differential: consider the curve $t\mapsto\phi(t,v)$. Then, the derivative of the curve at $0$ is $\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}$ while the derivative at $0$ of $N(\phi(t,v))$ is $\dfrac{\partial (N \circ \phi)}{\partial u}$.

Comment: P.S. This has nothing to do with the Gauss map. This is the situation for *any* differentiable function on the surface.